# Assigning an int literal to a long wrapper class in java

Tags: java, int, long-integer

Why is there a compilation error with `Long l = 3` and not with `Long l = 3L`?

The primitive data type `long` accepts both `3` and `3l`. I understand that `3` is an `int` literal - but it can't be assigned to a `Long` wrapper object? `int` is only 32 bits shouldn't it fit in a 64 bit integer type?

Answer (score 4):

Because there isn't an `int` to `Long` widening **and** autoboxing conversion, autoboxing converts from `long` to `Long` (but first the value must be *widened* from an `int` to a `long`). You could do `3L` as you have, or

```
Long l = Long.valueOf(3);
```

or

```
Long l = (long) 3;
```

Comment: ok but can you kindly explain me why the primitive datatype long accept the 3?

Comment: @ashley [JLS-5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) enumerates the **19** widening conversions, including "int to long, float, or double"

Comment: Thanks will refer to the doc

Answer (score 0):

For additional answer:

`3L` is equals to `(long)3` --> parse it to 3L as it is a long literal

**3 is a integer literal**

**3L is a long literal**

in a nutshell, they are different from each other that's why you need to parse int to long or vice versa.